# Converting wav file to mono

Tags: c#, audio, wav, naudio, pcm

I'm trying to convert a stereo .wav file to mono using NAudio. One requirement is that I cannot use any native calls, as I need to run this code on Azure. Here's what I came with:

```
using (var waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFileName))
    {
        var toMono = new StereoToMonoProvider16(waveFileReader);
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(destFileName, toMono);
    }
```

My code works without errors, but the output is a file that contains pure silence.

Is there any other way to convert a file to mono?

Comment: .wav file is an array of bytes. so you can proccess it without any external library. The only question is how do you define the convertion? I mean, if you have two channels - L,R - what is youe expected output? their sum? average?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I thought that I didn't have to spend time on figuring wav file format and code all that from scratch. Sure a library like NAudio should have something like that already, no?

In fact, I could do pretty much anything using mscorlib alone, but what's the point?

Comment: Why do you need mscorlib to read the wav file as byte array and then loop over the audio data and do simple calculation?

Comment: I mean, people can do all their tasks using mscorlib alone, but they still use external libraries to save time and effort. And I could solve my problem using bytes and stuff, but NAudio saved me a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide values for the `LeftVolume` and `RightVolume` properties of the `StereoToMonoProvider16`. For example, set them both to 0.5f to mix the channels, or set left to 1.0 and right to 0.0 to discard the right channel

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me.

```
public static void StereoToMono(string sourceFile, string outputFile)
    {
        using (var waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFile))
        {
            var outFormat = new WaveFormat(waveFileReader.WaveFormat.SampleRate, 1);
            using (var resampler = new MediaFoundationResampler(waveFileReader, outFormat))
            {
                WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, resampler);
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that `channels` parameter is passed `1` for `outFomat`.

Comment: It works on my PC, but, unfortunately, not on Azure -- Unable to load DLL 'mfplat.dll'. I wonder if it's possible to convert without using native DLLs.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me, even on Azure:

```
private void ConvertToMono(string sourceFileName, string destFileName) {
    var monoFormat = new WaveFormat(44100, 1);
    using (var waveFileReader = new WaveFileReader(sourceFileName))
    {
        var floatTo16Provider = new WaveFloatTo16Provider(waveFileReader);
        using (var provider = new WaveFormatConversionProvider(monoFormat, floatTo16Provider))
        {
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(destFileName, provider);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that I'm using an additional converter (`WaveFloatTo16Provider`), since the source was in the float format.